# Data is returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable, children

I have this sortable function in which I want to be able to add users to a group. When I drag the user from the user-table to the group-table, I want to able to check if that ID already exists in the group-table, and if it does I want to respond with a error-message. However, when I try to loop trou and get the ID's from the group-table, I'm getting a undefined value.

HTML-code:

```
<div class="userContainer">
    <div id="userDiv">
        <ul class="userList dragable" ></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="groupDiv">
        <select id="DropDown"></select>
        <input id="btnGetGroups" class="btn btn-success" type="button"
               value="Hämta grupper" />
        <select id="DropDownGroups"></select>
        <input id="btnShowGroups" class="btn btn-success" type="button"
               value="Visa grupp" />
        <ul class="usersOfGroupList dragable"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Here is the code for filling the group-table with current users:*

```
$('#btnShowGroups').click(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("DropDownGroups");
        groupId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        $('.usersOfGroupList').empty();

        $.getJSON("mylinkgoeshere" + groupId + "", function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                $('.usersOfGroupList').append($("<li id='userElement' data-userId='' ></li>").data('userId', value.Id).html(value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName));
                $(".usersOfGroupList").addClass("addBorder");
            });
        });
    });
```

As you can see I'm using 'userId' as key in the data-property here.

*The sortable-code looks like this:*

```
 $(".dragable").sortable({
            connectWith: ".usersOfGroupList",
            remove: function (e, ui) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var childs = $this.find('li');
                if (childs.length === 0) {
                    $this.text("Nothing");
                }
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                var array = [];
                var $this = $(this);
                var children = $this.find('li');
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    var specificId = children[i].item.data('userId');
                    array.push(specificId);
                    console.log(array);
                };
```

In the receive-property, I'm trying to get the current userIDs by looping trough all the li-elements and then push the ID's into a array, but it will only return undefined. I've debugged and the li-elements are there, but it gives me this error-message:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at HTMLUListElement.receive**

Comment: `children[i].item` is undefined....

Comment: I see you use strange loop, do `$this.find('li').each(function(i) {array.push($(this).data('userId'); });` - it is recommended for jQuery sets, as we see in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/), to `Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element. `

Comment: @skobaljic You are the man, thank you.